# match pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i match a expression in which first three characters are alphabets followed by a "-" and than 2 alphabets.

For eg. ABC-XY

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That very sentence pretty much spells out the answer for you.... if you know regexes at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only to test if the string matchs the pattern, use the test method:

```
function isValid(input) {
 return /^[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{2}$/.test(input);
}

isValid("ABC-XY"); // true
isValid("ABCD-XY"); // false
```

Basically the `/^[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{2}$/` RegExp looks for:

- The beginning of the string `^`
- Three uppercase letters `[A-Z]{3}`
- A dash literally `-`
- Two more uppercase letters `[A-Z]{2}`
- And the end of the string `$`

If you want to match alphanumeric characters, you can use `\w` instead of `[A-Z]`.

Resources:

- [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- [The RegExp Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/RegExp)
- [Using Regular Expressions with JavaScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
[A-Z]{3}-[A-Z]{2}
```

if you also want to allow lowercase, change `A-Z` to `A-Za-z`.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[a-zA-Z]{3}-[a-zA-Z]{2}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\w{3}-\w{2}/.test("ABC-XY")
true
```

it will match A-Za-z_ though.